# Android : getting trouble while implementing sliding menu

Tags: android, onclick, slidingmenu

I am trying to implement sliding menu with **jfeinstein10** library which i downloaded from [here](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu).

So i have used this below code.

```
SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
menu.setMenu(R.layout.activity_menu);
```

When i use this code directly in `onCreate` method then there is no issue, but when i put this code in button's click event like below.

```
Button mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.slidingMenu);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                try {
                    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
                    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
                    menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
                    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
                    menu.attachToActivity(MainActivity.this,
                            SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
                    menu.setMenu(R.layout.activity_menu);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

suddenly i am getting following error.

```
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.slidingtest/com.example.slidingtest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3254)
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3315)
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:459)
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:248)
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.<init>(SlidingMenu.java:217)
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.<init>(SlidingMenu.java:203)
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.<init>(SlidingMenu.java:178)
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at com.example.slidingtest.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:14)
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     ... 11 more
```

Any idea what is causing here.

**Edit**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/slidingMenu"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Click Me !" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where do you have this `SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);`?

Answer (score 0):

This

```
SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
```

must go into `onCreate`.

Context is available once activity is created.

Look at

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 03-20 04:19:12.246:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
>   03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at
>   android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
>   03-20 04:19:12.246: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at
>   android.view.View.(View.java:3254)

Comment: If i use this in onCreate then i am getting error in all `menu` in button;s click event.

Comment: and if i use `SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(MainActivity.this);` inside button's click event then i am not getting any error, but also when i click button it is not opening sliding menu.

Comment: this refers to activity context. inside annonymous inner class you use `MainActivity.this` which is activity context.

Comment: The error when i use `SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);` in onCreate is `java.lang.IllegalStateException: This SlidingMenu appears to already be attached
`

Comment: that means its already attached to the activity and look at the example in the docs.

Comment: In this case what is the solution, what should i do?

Comment: I suggest follow the sample. It has samples. ALso You could switch to native Navigation Drawer. I would recommend it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50106/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-innocentkiller)

Comment: i guess you also have the sliding menu in xml and you are trying to create it progrmatically and attach the same

Comment: @InnocentKiller can you post the xml also??